# Project broken with Bundler errors after RVM install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundler

I installed RVM and installed 3 different rubies: 1.8.7, ree, and 1.9.2.

I have a Rails 3.0.9 project that uses 1.8.7.

Now when I try to run the 3.0.9 project, I get this error:

```
Could not find xml-simple-1.1.0 in any of the sources
```

However, the following command:

```
bundle show xml-simple
```

yields:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/xml-simple-1.1.0
```

Looks right to me. What am I missing here? The application, when running, is clearly not seeing the right path. Yet Bundler, when run at the command line, sees it just fine. I am not certain where these paths are to be set. I am admittedly new to RVM, I installed it because I want to start a new edge project with 1.9.2.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to learn how to create a gemset, then switch to that gemset. You can always check your gem and ruby environment with rvm using:

```
rvm info
```

That's what clued me in. Once I "use"d the appropriate gemset where the gem was installed, it worked great.